# Django. Use Json file from context variable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django

I want to pass a list to Jquery and then use it with the Autocomplete jqueryui widget.
It is a small list, so I don't think I need a new request. So, I guess I don't need to use Jsquery's getJSON.

I have:

```
 json_list = json.dumps(list)
 context = {'json_list':json_list}
 return render(request, template, context)
```

in jquery:

```
var json_list = JSON.parse({{json_list}});
$("#field").autocomplete({
  source: json_list
 });
```

I get a Syntax Error on "&quot":

```
 var autores_json = JSON.parse([&quot;Friedrich Hayek&quot;, &quot;Milton Friedma...
```

Im kind of lost here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot the quotes.

```
var json_list = JSON.parse('{{json_list}}');
$("#field").autocomplete({
  source: json_list
 });
```

Also, I'm not sure whether it will recognize `&quot;` as a quote char, so maybe you should try:

```
var json_list = JSON.parse('{{json_list|safe}}');
$("#field").autocomplete({
  source: json_list
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` need a string, so add some quotes.

Second, it's having trouble with HTML entities. After ensuring `json_list` is a string, use

`JSON.parse(json_string.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));`

EDIT: As mentioned above, better to pass `safe` in then use regex.